# Read dxf Matlab,

Tags: matlab, autocad

I want to read dxf in matlab. Can anybody recommend me some link.
DXF contains 3d (**arc**, line, polylines),circle, cylinders etc.

I tried f_LectDxf.m from matlab file center but it can read only center , start and end angle of arc.

The following group codes apply to arc entities.

[image]

***How can I get starting and end points of arc using this knowledge.***

Attached is very small portion (just arc)

[image].